# Button to revert div classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "Buy" button and 2 tabpanels (one for product description and the other for a buy form). I am trying to make it so when I click in the Buy button it will hide the product description and show the buy form. I know that the shown tabpanel has the class: "tab-pane fade in active" and the hidden one has the class: "tab-pane fade". I can change the tabpanels manually, but I want to change them with a button. I tried some options like .toggleClass, or .addClass and .removeClass but they dont change anything in inspect element either. Here is a small portion of the code with jQuery included:

```
<button id="buythis" id="btn" type="button">Add to cart</button>
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#profile").toggleClass("tab-pane fade in active");
    });
</script>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a double id : `id="buythis" id="btn"`
If you remove `id="buythis"`, it works.

However, are you aware that "tab-pane fade in active" are 4 different classes? It will remove "tab-pane" and "fade", then add "in" and "active", is that intentional?

Comment: Hmm. I am new to web design and I thought I read somewhere that an element can have a lot of divs, oh well. Also, no, I thought anything within a `class="-- .."` is counted as a single class

Comment: no, ID means "unique IDentifier" and must be unique in the whole DOM, and each element can have only one ID.

Comment: either way, the button does nothing to the class. What can I do to make it functional?

Comment: @Codepen I don't think it does... It does nothing to the class.

Comment: The text toggles from black to red when you click the button because the "active" class toggles. It works. Check my codepen. Codepen is a tool, not a dude :)